# Tracking search query parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

My rails application revolves around searching for 1 specific record given various filters. I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to keep track of search queries so in the future we can either do reporting or a dashboard. Basically I need insight into what users are looking for.

This is what a search query would look like:

> http://localhost:3000/s?utf8=%E2%9C%93&location=New+York%2C+NY%2C+United+States&activity=Figure+Skating&start_time=Nov+13th+2015&end_time=Dec+25th+2015&period=morning&geolocation=%5B40.7127837%2C-74.00594130000002%5D

cleaner:

> http://localhost:3000/s?utf8=%E2%9C%93&location=&activity=&start_time=&end_time=&geolocation=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hook in your search controller method that stores the params used in every search. Perhaps you can create a new model called Analytics, where every time someone searches for something the Analytics stores all the values of the search... that way you can have all the information stored in your db and you can analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to track this via the Google Analytics:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=en